# unable to send post request using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

here i am sending data from socket client to socket server and after receiving the  request it has to send to node api

**the issue is im getting null ** on calling the socket server
below is my code

**Socket Client**

```
socket.connect();

socket.emit("posreq",JSON.stringify({ "title": "data"}));
```

**Socket Server**

```
var http = require('http'),
  io = require('socket.io'), // for npm, otherwise use require('./path/to/socket.io') 
  request = require('request'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // your normal server code 
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    res.end('Hello world');
  });
  
server.listen(4000);

// socket.io 
var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function (client) {
  // new client is here! 
  
  client.on('posreq', function (postdata) {
    request.post("http://localhost:3000/book", {
      body: postdata
    }, function (res) {
      console.log(res);
      client.send("post req called",postdata);
    });

  });




  client.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('connection closed');
  });

});
```

**Node api**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()
const port = 3000

let books = [{
    "title": "Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition",
   }];

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/book', (req, res) => {
    const book = req.body;

    // output the book to the console for debugging
    console.log(book);
  //  books.push(book);

    res.json('Book is added to the database');
});
```

I tried but unable to understand the issue
Note : How can i convert the Socket server to express js code

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the port you are listening to, you must listen to port 3000 also, try to change this to `server.listen(3000);`

Comment: The first argument passed to the callback function of request.post is an error. So it's actualy good thing that you get null, means there was no error. Use `request.post(....., function (err, res, body) { console.log(err, res, body); ...`

Answer (score 4):

As far I understand you are willing to use express instead of HTTP and that will solve your problem. And in the below code, I have used express as well as HTTP. Try code below

```
const express=require("express")
const app=express()
const server=require("http").createServer(app)
const socket=require("socket.io")(server)
server.listen(4000,()=>console.log(`Listening to port 4000`))

socket.on('connection', function (client) {

client.on('posreq', function (postdata) {
 request.post("http://localhost:3000/book", {
   body: postdata
 }, function (res) {
   console.log(res);
   client.send("post req called",postdata);
 });

});


client.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('connection closed');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you need few modification,
[Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is depricated so better to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or other alternative.

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const axios = require('axios')
const app = express()

const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app)
const socket = require("socket.io")(server)

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '16mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '16mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));

app.get('/', (req,res)=> res.send("Hello world"));

socket.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('posreq', async (body) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/book", { body })
            socket.send("post req called", data);
        } catch (error) {
            socket.send("post req error", error);
        }

    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('connection closed');
    });

});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Spinning 3000`))
```